# AsycnSocket not connecting to TCP serial port over wifi

Tags: iphone, ssl, tcp, asyncsocket

I have an iPhone app that I run on the simulator. XCode ver 3.2.6/4.3. I am trying to communicate with a radio on a serial port of a PC over wifi, both on the same server... I've tried NSStream and GCDAsyncSocket (just to make sure). The radio has its own IP address and port number. It's actually a TCP/IP wifi module. After changing the remote access on the PC to accept my IP address, I am finally able to connect but I get kicked off immediately, I'm assuming it's when I try to read or write. Same happens when using Telnet, connects then disconnects. The radio issues *HELLO* when someone connects, so Telnet must try to read since data is sent. I'm guessing. I thought since I am able to connect, I should be able to read/write. (Yes, newbie here)

I would appreciate any thoughts or direction. I've been researching for over a week now and going bonkers.

Thanks. I added the code below as well as the error message.

This is the error message:
    socketDidDisconnect:withError: "Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain 
    Code=-9844 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 
    -9844.)" UserInfo=0x4c38a60 {}"

```
- (IBAction)performConnection:(id)sender 
{
    asyncSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];   
    NSError *error = nil;
    uint16_t port = [[[self serverPort] text] intValue];

    if (![asyncSocket connectToHost:[serverAddr text] onPort:port error:&error])
    {
        DDLogError(@"Unable to connect due to invalid configuration: %@", error);
        [self debugPrint:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to connect due to invalid configuration: %@", error]];
    }
    else
    {
        DDLogVerbose(@"Connecting...IP:%@, port:%i", [serverAddr text], port);
    }   
}

- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port
{
    DDLogInfo(@"socket:%p didConnectToHost:%@ port:%hu", sock, host, port);

    NSMutableDictionary *settings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];
    [settings setObject:@"XXX.XXX.X.XXX"
             forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLPeerName];

    // In fact, don't even validate the certificate chain
    [settings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]
             forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain];
    [settings setObject:(NSString*)kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel
             forKey:(NSString*)kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL];

    DDLogVerbose(@"Starting TLS with settings:\n%@", settings);

    [sock startTLS:settings];

    [self debugPrint:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"socket:didConnectToHost:%@ port:%hu", host, port]];

    //[sock readDataToData:[GCDAsyncSocket CRLFData] withTimeout:-1 tag:0]; 
    [sock readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];

}

- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didWriteDataWithTag:(long)tag
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"socket:didWriteDataWithTag:");
    [sock readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];

}


- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"socket:didReadData:withTag:");

    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data  encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"read response:%@", response);
    [self debugPrint:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Read:  \n%@",response]];
    [response release];

    //NSData *newline = [@"\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 
    //[sock readDataToData:newline withTimeout:-1 tag: 0]; 
    [sock readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];

}

- (IBAction)sendBuf:(id)sender 
{
    if ([[bufOut text] length] > 0) 
    {
            NSString *requestStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [bufOut text]];
        NSLog(@"Sending:%@",requestStr);
        NSData *requestData = [requestStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        [asyncSocket writeData:requestData withTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];
        [self debugPrint:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sent:  \n%@",requestStr]];
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you should add some code to exemplify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a partial solution (by sheer accident). It seems the radio or how the radio is setup only allows me to connect/read/write if my app or iMac initiates the connection. It's fine with another PC. Both can initiate a connection and everything works. Still need to resolve this but at least I know my code is working.
Thanks to anyone who gave my problem some thought.